# How to create a relationship to an ObjEntity in another DataMap?

Tags: apache-cayenne

Somewhere i read, that it's possible with Cayenne to have relationships connecting entities from two different DataMaps, just like WebObjects EOModeler. I am not able to create such relationship in Cayenne Modeler 4.0RC1 and 4.1M2 - the target entity dropdown lists only entities from the current map. Any hints?

See screenshot [Apache CayenneModeler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83ZAE.png)

Comment: Did a quick check. DbEntities from other data maps are just there for me in all Modeler versions, including older 3.1.3. Maybe you can provide sample of project.xml file where you see this problem or screenshot of it?

Comment: edit: screenshot added. 
Additional info: all 4 DataMaps created with "Tools - Import EOModel"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create DbRelationship first and use it. In this case you can choose any DbEntity in any DataMap. See [this tutorial](https://cayenne.apache.org/docs/4.1/getting-started-guide/#mapping-database-relationships) for details.

Comment: Read the fine manual... Well i did, and it works fine. Thank you for your time!